# How to make default value of a @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I want to use the @Html.TextBoxFor for my form. and for this field I want for the field is autofilled or the default value is "IDR" and it's disable or greyed out. I already using it like this

```
<div class="col-1">
<div class="input-group">                                                 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.dataKinerjaDebitur.TaksasiNonFakurs, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "IDR", @placeholder = "IDR", @readonly = "readonly" })                                              
</div>
</div>
```

the value won't pass into the controller, resulted in null. any help?

Comment: You should change `Value` to `value` , which should solve your problem

Comment: [The `placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) specifies the placeholder text for an `<input>` element. That value is *not* submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view keep it as it is now, but put a check in your post action

```
public ActionResult Post (MyModel model)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.dataKinerjaDebitur.TaksasiNonFakurs))
  model.dataKinerjaDebitur.TaksasiNonFakurs="IDR";
}
```